# How can I optimize an SQL query for calculating word frequency?

Tags: sql, postgresql, tf-idf, tsvector

I am trying to populate two tables:

`token`:

```
 word  | df(the number of documents containing a word) 
==========
"dog"  | 5    
"cat"  | 2    
"horse"| 1
```

`token_count`:

```
tokenid | docid| tf(the number of times a word occurs in a document)
====================
   1    |  1   | 6
   2    |  2   | 2
   3    |  2   | 1
```

using the data from `documents`:

```
id   |  title  |     body
=============================
1    |  "dog"  | "about dogs" 
2    |  "cats" | "about cats"
```

To do that I use  `ts_stat( 'select to_tsvector(''english'', body) from documents' )` which returns a table with the document frequency for the word and also the number of times that words appears in the entire column. While the second column is exactly what I need for the `token` table the third column shows the document frequency for the entire column.

```
word | ndoc | nentry
====================
dog  | 5    | 6
cat  | 2    | 2
horse| 1    | 1
```

This code populates the `token` table and does it in 3sec for a hundred documents.

```
INSERT INTO token (word, document_frequency)
SELECT
    word,
    ndoc
FROM 
    ts_stat( 'select to_tsvector(''english'', body) from documents' );
```

I tried running the following code on a smaller dataset of 15 documents and it worked but when I'm trying to run this on the current dataset(100 docs) it never stops running.

```
WITH temp_data AS (
    SELECT id , 
           (ts_stat('select to_tsvector(''english'', body) from documents where id='||id)).*
    FROM documents 
)
INSERT INTO token_count (docid, tokenid, tf)
SELECT
    id,
    (SELECT id FROM token WHERE word = temp_data.word LIMIT 1),
    nentry
FROM temp_data;
```

How can I optimize this query?

**EXPLAIN ANALYZE** for the dataset of 15 documents:

```
"Insert on token_count  (cost=1023803.22..1938766428.23 rows=9100000 width=28) (actual time=59875.204..59875.206 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  CTE temp_data"
"    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..1023803.22 rows=9100000 width=44) (actual time=0.144..853.320 rows=42449 loops=1)"
"          ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..45553.23 rows=9100000 width=36) (actual time=0.142..809.366 rows=42449 loops=1)"
"                ->  Seq Scan on wikitable  (cost=0.00..19.10 rows=910 width=4) (actual time=0.010..0.029 rows=16 loops=1)"
"  ->  CTE Scan on temp_data  (cost=0.00..1937742625.00 rows=9100000 width=28) (actual time=0.509..59652.279 rows=42449 loops=1)"
"        SubPlan 2"
"          ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..212.92 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1.381..1.381 rows=1 loops=42449)"
"                ->  Seq Scan on token  (cost=0.00..425.84 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=1.372..1.372 rows=1 loops=42449)"
"                      Filter: ((word)::text = temp_data.word)"
"                      Rows Removed by Filter: 10384"
"Planning Time: 0.202 ms"
"Execution Time: 59876.350 ms"
```

**EXPLAIN ANALYZE** for the dataset of 30 documents:

```
"Insert on token_count  (cost=1023803.22..6625550803.23 rows=9100000 width=28) (actual time=189910.438..189910.439 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  CTE temp_data"
"    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..1023803.22 rows=9100000 width=44) (actual time=0.191..2018.758 rows=92168 loops=1)"
"          ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..45553.23 rows=9100000 width=36) (actual time=0.189..1919.726 rows=92168 loops=1)"
"                ->  Seq Scan on wikitable  (cost=0.00..19.10 rows=910 width=4) (actual time=0.013..0.053 rows=31 loops=1)"
"  ->  CTE Scan on temp_data  (cost=0.00..6624527000.00 rows=9100000 width=28) (actual time=1.009..189412.022 rows=92168 loops=1)"
"        SubPlan 2"
"          ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..727.95 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=2.029..2.029 rows=1 loops=92168)"
"                ->  Seq Scan on token  (cost=0.00..727.95 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=2.020..2.020 rows=1 loops=92168)"
"                      Filter: ((word)::text = temp_data.word)"
"                      Rows Removed by Filter: 16463"
"Planning Time: 0.234 ms"
"Execution Time: 189913.688 ms"
```

Comment: [How long is never](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11514/how-long-is-never)?   Can you add an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, like is done in this question:  [How do I increase the speed of my Postgres statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34277926/how-do-i-increase-the-speed-of-my-postgres-select-statement)

Comment: Yesterday I tried running that piece of code on the dataset of 100 000 docs and had to shut it down after an hour and a half.
 Just added `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`  for a dataset of 15 documents. I'll try to do the same now for 30 documents.

Comment: Adding an index on the column `word` in the table `token` might solve part of your problem.

Comment: The query will always be slow unless the field is covered by a full text search index. Even then, you're trying to split and count every single word in that index, not find a specific match. This will be slow.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you want to rank the results you can use `ts_rank`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I need to calculate various tf-idf combinations for a test project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a demo that doesn't use ts_stat to get the word counts.

Instead it uses a lateral join to an unnesting of the ts_vector.

> ```
> create table documents (
>  document_id serial primary key, 
>  title varchar(30) not null, 
>  body text not null
> );
>
> insert into documents (title, body) values
>   ('dogs', 'the dog barked at the cat, but the cat ignored her.')
> , ('cats', 'cats kill more birds than dogs kill cats')
>
> create table tokens (
>  token_id serial primary key, 
>  word varchar(30),
>  df int
> )
>
> insert into tokens (word, df)
> SELECT word, ndoc
> FROM ts_stat('select to_tsvector(''english'', body) from documents');
> ```

> ```
> select * from tokens order by df desc
> ```
>
> ```
> token_id | word  | df
> -------: | :---- | -:
>        3 | dog   |  2
>        4 | cat   |  2
>        1 | kill  |  1
>        2 | ignor |  1
>        5 | bird  |  1
>        6 | bark  |  1
> ```

> ```
> create table token_counts (
>  document_id int, 
>  token_id int,
>  tf int, 
>  primary key (document_id, token_id), 
>  foreign key (document_id) references documents(document_id), 
>  foreign key (token_id) references tokens(token_id)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO token_counts (
>  document_id, 
>  token_id, 
>  tf
> )
> select 
>  doc.document_id, 
>  tok.token_id, 
>  lex.total
> from documents as doc
> cross join lateral (
>   select lexeme, cardinality(positions) as total
>   from unnest(to_tsvector('english', doc.body)) as tsvector
> ) as lex
> inner join tokens as tok
>   on tok.word = lex.lexeme;
> ```

> ```
> select title, word, tf
> from token_counts cnt
> join documents doc using(document_id)
> join tokens tok using(token_id)
> order by document_id, token_id
> ```

| title | word | tf |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dogs | ignor | 1 |
| dogs | dog | 1 |
| dogs | cat | 2 |
| dogs | bark | 1 |
| cats | kill | 2 |
| cats | dog | 1 |
| cats | cat | 2 |
| cats | bird | 1 |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=53842a6d22b47ffff7b242b123fc8aa8)*

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. Took it 18 seconds on a 1000 doc dataset.

Comment: Thx. 1000 doc doesn't seem so many to me actually. Guess there are some really big books among them.